# error: markup following root element must be well formed

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to convert this ER diagram to XML using XSD
[image: Trying to convert ER diagram to XML using xsd]

Hi, I was trying to convert an ER diagram to XML format with XSD but came across above error and I am not able to figure it out.

This is XML file..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<company xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema_instance" xsi:SchemaLocation="companyxsd.xsd" companyName="abc" address="hj">
    <department dname="dfsdf" deptphoneno="1232321" deptfaxno="2323" deptemail="fefsf">
        <employee empid="fsd" ename="fuehuf" emailid="fhueh" phoneno="364764">
        </employee>
        <contractEmployee name="fdsf" phoneno="12345">
        </contractEmployee>
    </department>
</company>
```

This is `companyxsd.xsd`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
    <xs:attribute name="companyName" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:attribute name="address" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:attribute name="dname" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:attribute name="deptphoneno" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:attribute name="deptfaxno" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:attribute name="deptemail" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:attribute name="empid" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:attribute name="ename" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:attribute name="emailid" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:attribute name="phoneno" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />

    <xs:element name="employee">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute ref="empid"/>
            <xs:attribute ref="ename"/>
            <xs:attribute ref="emailid"/>
            <xs:attribute ref="phoneno"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>


    <xs:element name="contractEmployee">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute ref="name"/>
            <xs:attribute ref="phoneno"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>


    <xs:element name="department">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="employee"/>
                <xs:element ref="contractEmployee"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute ref="dname"/>
            <xs:attribute ref="deptphoneno"/>
            <xs:attribute ref="deptfaxno"/>
            <xs:attribute ref="deptemail"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="company">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="department"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute ref="companyName"/>
            <xs:attribute ref="address"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I'm new to XML so don't really know if it's right. I tried to search on net about this specific problem but couldn't find any satisfactory answer. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Which error? What is the requested result?

Comment: error is: Exception: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

Comment: Result is correct implementation of ER diagram (image link is linked above)

Comment: Is there a possibility to draw that or another similar ER and export it as XML? so you can see, what is really needed as a result.

Comment: I don't know if it's even possible to export ER to xml. I just have the image.

Comment: You have an error in your XSD file making it "not well-formed". The line `<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>` should not end with `.../>` but rather with `...>`. The closing tag must be at the end of file.

Comment: @zx485 Thanks! That worked.. Silly noobie mistakes.. xD